# How to prepare the generated pre-trained MATLAB neural network function arguments?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have trained the neural network as follow:

```
[x,t] = maglev_dataset;
maglevNet = narxnet(1:2,1:2,10);
[X,Xi,Ai,T] = preparets(maglevNet,x,{},t);
maglevNet = train(maglevNet,X,T,Xi,Ai);
[y,xf,af] = maglevNet(X,Xi,Ai);
```

and then generate function:

```
genFunction(maglevNet,'maglevFcn');
[y2,xf,af] = maglevFcn(X,Xi,Ai);
accuracy2 = max(abs(cell2mat(y)-cell2mat(y2)));
mcc -W lib:libMaglev -T link:lib maglevFcn
```

or

```
genFunction(maglevNet,'maglevFcn','MatrixOnly','yes');
x1 = cell2mat(X(1,:)); % Convert each input to matrix
x2 = cell2mat(X(2,:));
xi1 = cell2mat(Xi(1,:)); % Convert each input state to matrix
xi2 = cell2mat(Xi(2,:));
[y3,xf1,xf2] = maglevFcn(x1,x2,xi1,xi2);
```

The question is :The arguments of the generated function is from [X,Xi,Ai,T] = preparets(maglevNet,x,{},t); and preparets depends on maglevNet. How could I prepare the arguments when I run the generated function alone or apply it in C++ or others as dll?